# reCaptcha : Cannot find frame to click on audio button : Python & selenium

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

Im trying to click on audio button on a reCaptcha popup(see my photo) but i cannot, this is my code :
[image]

```
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
all_frames = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
self.driver.switch_to.frame(all_frames[0])
self.driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-audio-button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by this code :

```
self.driver.switch_to_frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
frames = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
self.driver.switch_to.frame(frames[-1])
self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'recaptcha-audio-button').click()
```